# How to turn a table into a single block of text with scrapy

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a table which looks like the below.

```
<table class="table">
    <caption>Caption</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Title</th>
            <td>Detail</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Title 2</th>
            <td>Detail 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How would you set up scrapy so my output file generates an output similar to the below?!

```
Title: Detail
Title2: Detail2
```

Currently I can get all the text using two css selectors (one for the td's and one for the th's) but I would love to be able to combine these!

Unfortunately the number of rows differs from page to page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath:

```
tabledata={}
for i in response.xpath("//table[@class='table']//tr")
    tabledata[i.xpath("th/text()").extract_first()] = i.xpath("td/text()").extract_first()
```

Output

```
{"Title":"Detail", "Title 2":"Detail 2"}
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, sorry for not being clear but do you know how I can turn this array into something like ["Title: Detail - Title2: Detail2"]?


I can use the following to get ["Title" , "Detail", "Title2" , "Detail2"]:


    response.xpath("//table[@class='table']//th/text() | //table[@class='table']//td/text()").extract()